# Finding a power series solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, power-series

It's a problem on Qing Han's book. Given:

$$ u_{tt}-u_{xx}-u=0 \in \mathbb{R}\times (0,\infty)\\
u(x,0)=x, u_t(x,0)=-x$$

Then, there is a power series solution in $(0,0)$ and find this solution.

The existence can be verified by Cauchy-Kovalevskaya, because all the coefficients are analytic.
Now, using the initial condition, can we deduce that the power series solution has order 2? How can I show this explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what your definition of the order of a power series is, but I solved this exercise simply by making the ansatz
\begin{align}
u(t,x)=\sum_{n,k}c_{n,k}x^nt^k
\end{align}

You can plug this expression into the PDE and set the coefficients of $x^nt^k$ equal to zero. Using the initial conditions it's not very difficult to work out the coefficients $c_{n,k}$.

The solution is given by

> \begin{align} u(t,x)=xe^{-t} \end{align}

Comment: oh ok, i was insecure with the computations! but thank u! I got the result.